# javascript Share code between my client and my server folders

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, directory

I have a directory that contains two folder : my server app (`NodeJS`) and my client app (`ReactJS`).

My directory structure looks like this :

```
root/
|- client/
   |- package.json
   |- src/
      |- ...
|- server/
   |- package.json
   |- src/
      |- ...
```

How can I add a `common` folder at the root of my directory to share enums and utils with both my server and my client ?

Thanks!

Comment: You add a folder 'common' under root and then make sure all the scripts importing enums and such use the correct path. What is the problem?

Comment: or dont share it at all, or else you start to couple your client and server - you may as well build a monolith

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple solutions:

- create a folder `common` under root and just require the files you need from your files. But you could end up with "long" require such as require("../../../../../common/file")
- use module-alias to avoid that problem: https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias
- you could make `common` a local module (using `file:`) and install it in package.json
  https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "file:../common"
  }
}
```

Then you can just require what you need easily

Comment: Nodejs uses require() and react import. Wouldn't that cause issues ?