# We share a yarn JS folder w/ client & server,

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, yarnpkg

#### The situation:

- client and server both share a folder `shared`
- when we change shared in our development flow, we want the corresponding references to change in customer and server
- server works because somehow with `npm` it seems to work, shared and server use `npm`
- customer doesn't work and uses yarn
- mixed typescript and js project

#### Code Structure:

```
root/
|- client/
   |- package.json
   |- src/
      |- ...
|- server/
   |- package.json
   |- src/
      |- ...
|- shared/
   |- package.json // we don't want to change version every change
   |- src/
      |- ...
```

#### What's been tried

- 3 solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635266/javascript-share-code-between-my-client-and-my-server-folders)

  - > create a folder common under root and just require the files you need from your files. But you could end up with "long" require such as require("../../../../../common/file")
  - long require doesn't work with resolution with webpack - and isn't a nice solution
  - > use module-alias to avoid that problem: https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias
  - module-alias *seems* to be the same solution as the next one, in how it behaves.
  - > you could make common a local module (using file:) and install it in package.json https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths
  - we currently do this, but we still have to reinstall the `shared` folder on a change, we currently use `yarn upgrade shared` which takes a long time and still requires us to know when we need to run it.
- in addition we've attempted to get `yarn link` working but doesn't seem to link properly
- we've attempted to use a `post-pull` hook with [`husky`](https://github.com/typicode/husky) to run `yarn upgrade shared` but it's too slow to run every pull especially since it's not needed often
- we've considered a true mono-repo 'package' like Lerna but still don't think that it's necessary for the cost to migrate
- [link-module-alias](https://github.com/Rush/link-module-alias) to sym link folders on post install script, but this fails [with typescript files](https://github.com/Rush/link-module-alias/issues/2)

### Goal

- either

  - find a way to automatically sync these in `dev` environement
  - find a solution that installs/updates manually - but is fast and can be run on every pull
  - find a way to automate running `yarn upgrade shared` that runs (roughly) only when needed not all the time
  - I guess we could find a way to automate the version increment on any change of `shared`'s `version` key, and then it's tracked, we could run `yarn install` and that work work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find solution was that we were using React-Native and therefore the normal steps for syncing would work for the IDE but not the React-Native app.

[Here](https://medium.com/@dushyant_db/how-to-import-files-from-outside-of-root-directory-with-react-native-metro-bundler-18207a348427) is a great article describing how to get metro bundler working with it - however for Typescript we added it to the TSConfig and for the IDE we still needed to add it to our package using the `file:../shared` directive.